# Docker node app can't connect linked mysql container

Tags: mysql, node.js, docker, express, networking

I've got a simple connection refused error but I dont' know were it's coming from.
Simply clone this repo https://github.com/allogic/domain_driven_design and go into the folder "services/registration" from there do `docker-compose up`.

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  database:
    container_name: 'database'
    image: 'mysql:8.0.15'
    restart: 'always'
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: 'registration'
      MYSQL_USER: 'root'
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'root'
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'root'
    expose:
      - '3306'

  registration:
    container_name: 'registration'
    image: 'node:8.15.1'
    restart: 'always'
    working_dir: '/usr/src/app'
    command: 'npm start'
    volumes:
      - './src:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    depends_on:
      - 'database'
    links:
      - 'database'
```

When I exec into the registration container, I can ping the database and it resolves the dns name but the node app cannot.

```js
const express = require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');

const app = express();

const db = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'database',
  port: 3306,
  user: 'root',
  password: 'root',
  database: 'registration'
});

try {
  db.connect();
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
}

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World\n');
});

app.listen(3000);
```

And here the error message

```
> registration@1.0.0 start /usr/src/app
> node app.js

events.js:183
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.19.0.2:3306
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1191:14)
    --------------------
    at Protocol._enqueue (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:144:48)
    at Protocol.handshake (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:51:23)
    at Connection.connect (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:118:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/app.js:15:6)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! registration@1.0.0 start: `node app.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the registration@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2019-03-05T15_17_18_189Z-debug.log
```

log for `docker inspect mysql`

```
[
    {
        "Id": "sha256:81f094a7e4ccc963fde3762e86625af76b6339924bf13f1b7bd3c51dbcfda988",
        "RepoTags": [
            "mysql:8.0.15",
            "mysql:latest"
        ],
        "RepoDigests": [
            "mysql@sha256:a571337738c9205427c80748e165eca88edc5a1157f8b8d545fa127fc3e29269"
        ],
        "Parent": "",
        "Comment": "",
        "Created": "2019-02-06T07:06:04.898919867Z",
        "Container": "93d3c07fe0cba1f21dcc2e8e644ac8a897305eefee402f270dd6b1b2652635fc",
        "ContainerConfig": {
            "Hostname": "93d3c07fe0cb",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3306/tcp": {},
                "33060/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.7",
                "MYSQL_MAJOR=8.0",
                "MYSQL_VERSION=8.0.15-1debian9"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "#(nop) ",
                "CMD [\"mysqld\"]"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:f6ef3ab29f84d76d5b484c15354757977544e81d5da417d95c4116d682c0c331",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/mysql": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {}
        },
        "DockerVersion": "18.06.1-ce",
        "Author": "",
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": false,
            "AttachStderr": false,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "3306/tcp": {},
                "33060/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
                "GOSU_VERSION=1.7",
                "MYSQL_MAJOR=8.0",
                "MYSQL_VERSION=8.0.15-1debian9"
            ],
            "Cmd": [
                "mysqld"
            ],
            "ArgsEscaped": true,
            "Image": "sha256:f6ef3ab29f84d76d5b484c15354757977544e81d5da417d95c4116d682c0c331",
            "Volumes": {
                "/var/lib/mysql": {}
            },
            "WorkingDir": "",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "docker-entrypoint.sh"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": null
        },
        "Architecture": "amd64",
        "Os": "linux",
        "Size": 476982381,
        "VirtualSize": 476982381,
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e844699b8b52fe17126eb3fffad064c33c3604ef1d15c8d1db07cd3a8d42a9f6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/b7feb6ff662169e92a080cdfd0016a6171f4509dc223a1143f859f0855383286/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/d215a62d46a307c23192f3b35a23915bf2d1793785970fc6ee2b9fb54ba1f9cc/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/4e0cf7d7d6d3b22f3962b6cea7372a4a6428e30266b893c5b43ab6eaa8545813/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c40f3b76ca01fa8ac1776a21c5018da263b9340fad18c9f76e0a5785896526a6/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c8dfb8cf9a1d808d3b50127387cc7cd14f6877dbbb8a1ef9f9c8794f389fde41/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2ebda49992fb5c703d4fd07658f88a6332df76e8df75a22741c477e23a0796ab/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/212abc22f2c50d69194fae07d459db74cb4bd965157ae886095b13bb0e43c1f5/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/c136d29eb2119905dc5890c0a7b7cb4010d2040838a05270f8277dfaadd23139/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/64b1725f0456a234d4b17f2d7315cbba3dc23b84775b4120938e97b8075da3c3/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/2250130aac197d5a0d9f9e443aff2620c3524ca5b7e97fd94f4653d782a165a0/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/731b309199a97bbec5618839895a33533715d9222640bc1631b10240df36f1a2/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/731b309199a97bbec5618839895a33533715d9222640bc1631b10240df36f1a2/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/731b309199a97bbec5618839895a33533715d9222640bc1631b10240df36f1a2/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "RootFS": {
            "Type": "layers",
            "Layers": [
                "sha256:0a07e81f5da36e4cd6c89d9bc3af643345e56bb2ed74cc8772e42ec0d393aee3",
                "sha256:3d33930b279aa4a88fe6dc381a0d4a2aca3a5cd0915565e41e9cf87174ca114e",
                "sha256:7412b239e6a1c4a423a484a368f31fba65df0cb2e35bcf89d0d0e17a5631ed56",
                "sha256:7756685f09e90e82438dd155b145875a02513a785efab1095b05f070b1d5de88",
                "sha256:7d390c8db6fd855d93a68a3beab4b55571b29f603e472fc122c7e5b4f90e36fd",
                "sha256:73ea790d3afa18621591a36a24c1254d68cb7ac66a6decc0d61df87ec30d7450",
                "sha256:5d6846033b0c8ad9f20a4d9330437440877f26d9f5ab8a1fb7cfe2209f14e92c",
                "sha256:506f749581f6ccda79e3a772666a9192f760628ec1035aef4524d658bb2e1e33",
                "sha256:a1cb89945ac3ad7c0a0e91a613fdec4dc3f648b388c8e91d091a1d6411d6636d",
                "sha256:8103990ddb33fb3195aed9edaeb522cd1a40bbc7fd57d358b1b52bb5290a9251",
                "sha256:3aa676232fffeb4b0baeb760f1071736df9290e934f58ffbb5c8d4227920aabf",
                "sha256:6e4a6c599b1d886a3565fe023cacd2724a8526ac591541604623b9507fe00891"
            ]
        },
        "Metadata": {
            "LastTagTime": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        }
    }
]
```

log for `docker logs database`

```
Initializing database
2019-03-05T15:17:16.039600Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2019-03-05T15:17:16.039689Z 0 [System] [MY-013169] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.15) initializing of server in progress as process 28
2019-03-05T15:17:19.335390Z 5 [Warning] [MY-010453] [Server] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
2019-03-05T15:17:20.707524Z 0 [System] [MY-013170] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.15) initializing of server has completed
Database initialized
MySQL init process in progress...
mbind: Operation not permitted
2019-03-05T15:17:23.248237Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2019-03-05T15:17:23.248303Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.15) starting as process 79
2019-03-05T15:17:23.723233Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-03-05T15:17:23.730096Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2019-03-05T15:17:23.763955Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.15'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2019-03-05T15:17:23.828356Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock'
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1396 (HY000) at line 1: Operation CREATE USER failed for 'root'@'%'
2019-03-05T15:17:31.369099Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2019-03-05T15:17:31.369163Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.15) starting as process 12019-03-05T15:17:33.271312Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting crash recovery...
2019-03-05T15:17:33.279645Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] Crash recovery finished.
2019-03-05T15:17:33.401824Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2019-03-05T15:17:33.405919Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2019-03-05T15:17:33.418808Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.15'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
2019-03-05T15:17:33.497722Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock' bind-address: '::' port: 33060
```

Comment: what is the result of docker inspect for `mysql` ? and what is the status in the mysql log is it ready to accept connections ? as it might need few seconds until mysql is ready

Comment: I guess it is ready to accept connections.. I've tested it with simple curl

Comment: Please update the inspection result with the mysql container not the mysql image. But I can tell from the error that the nodejs application can resolve the DNS to an IP. all you need to check is to ensure that mysql is actually works as expected by checking the container logs for mysql

Comment: Seems like it can't create the user.

Comment: Can you start or restart only nodejs container with keeping mysql container as it is ? and check if you will get the same error ?

Comment: I got a idffrent error this time.. so it seems like the node container can resolve the dns but as the database logs tell the mysql container has problems with creating the root user.

Answer (score 1):

`depends_on` not a verification that MySQL is actually ready to receive connections. It will start the second container once the database container is running regardless it was ready for connections or not which could lead to such an issue with your application as it expects the database to be ready which might not be true.

Quoted from [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/):

> depends_on does not wait for db and redis to be “ready” before starting web - only until they have been started.

If you need to wait for a service to be ready see [Controlling startup order](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) for more on this problem and strategies for solving it.

MySQL root user cannot be created due to setting `MYSQL_USER` to root because this user already exist in the database and it tries to create another. if you need to use the root user itself you can use only this variable `MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD` or change the value of `MYSQL_USER` so you can securely use it in your application instead of the root user.

Comment: It's not the express server from were the error is coming from

Comment: Can you please explain the error with the message ?

Comment: @grapes Thanks! I missed this point :D I have updated my answer